# Unwanted double quotes around server response in Python Flask-RESTful

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have an issue using python Flask-RESTful.
Consider the code below:

```
Class ServiceAPI(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return 'Hello, World!', 200
```

Then the client receives:

```
"Hello, World!"
```

instead of

```
Hello, World!
```

the extra double quotes are undesired. How can I avoid them? I don't want to solve the issue by stripping/trimming the data received, in the client.

Comment: (Not on my main pc with Flask so I can't test) But what happens when you return a variable with that string ?

Comment: @MooingRawr I tested it, the result was the same.